# Pulling table data with mixed element types

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to pull data from a table using Python and Selenium however a few of the columns have a mix between gif and text. When I print the text element it returns the text along with blanks were the gif elements are within the column. However when I prints the gif elements, it returns all the gifs from the table (not just the column) without any blanks for the text fields. Any ideas how I can pull both elements types from the column? Thanks.

Table example:

```
<td class="X">
<img src="/a/b/c/d.gif">
<td>
```

and

```
<td class="X">
<div class="default-value">Not Applicable</div>
</td>
```

Code for text

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("x")
   for post in posts:
   print(post.text)
```

Code for gif

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img'):
    print(element.get_attribute("src"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find all `td` elements first, then, for every `td` decide if you want to get the text or the `src` attribute of the `img` element:

```
posts = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("td.x")
for post in posts:
    images = post.find_elements_by_tag_name("img")
    if images:
         print(images[0].get_attribute("src"))
    else:
         print(post.text)
```